# Default php server unable to access magento2 on MAC

Tags: php, magento2

I am trying to run magento2 on my MAC machine by using default Apache server.
I have installed all other required dependencies.
Increased memory limits and other limits in php.ini
Also installed Elastic Search, just to go with default behavior.

Then in my project's directory I ran this command

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80
```

When I try to access in browser by typing 127.0.0.1 it says localhost refused to connect

but when I do 127.0.0.1/pub
It displays me homepage but without styling, I am assuming that is happening because of path issues.
Here How home page looks like

[image]

I installed it on ubuntu but there i didn't had to use pub in url. Kindly, mention what I am missing.

**Project location:** /usr/local/opt/magento
**Php Version:**

```
PHP 8.1.17 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2023 13:20:31) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.17, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.17, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

and **mysql table details:**

[image]

Comment: default php server don't support .htaccess

Comment: Can you kindly mention, what should I do?

Comment: You need an apache (or nginx) server configured to use Magento 2. The magento docs have orientations, you can also find some tutorials on internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the router script provided with magento2 because the builtin php server does not support .htaccess files but magento depends on rewrites.

Use `php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t ./pub/ ./phpserver/router.php` as specified in [magento2/phpserver](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/phpserver#how-to-run-magento) docs.

Comment: This takes me to maintainence mode

Comment: @MuhammadFahad Does serving the magento2 app through apache/nginx not lead to maintenance mode ? You might want to check if the maintenance flag is specified with `bin/magento maintenance:status` and if so disable it with `bin/magento maintenance:disable`. Also check if `var/.maintenance.flag` exists and delete it if so.